# Element background color not displaying in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a page with 4 `<div>`'s that have `float: left` applied to them inside of a container element. The container has `background: #ffffff` applied to it, but it is not working as I would expect in IE (8, specifically). It works fine in Chrome and FireFox.

I know that if I remove my slider from the container, everything displays as I would expect it. So it has something to do with that, I'm just not sure what it is.

Here is how it should look:
[image: Chrome]

Here is how it is displaying in IE:

### [image: IE]

CSS:

```
/* Container */
.main-content {
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

/* Columns (Wrecked Vehicles, Welcome, Inv Search) */
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 289px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

/* Slider */
.slider {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="col n1">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="slider">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="col n2">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="col n3">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to the `.main_content`. The reason the backgorund isn't showing is because, due to all the children floating, the container has zero "real" height.

Comment: Well, that worked. Very strange to me. I thought that using `clear: both;` would take care of this issue. How is IE interpreting it differently from Chrome & FireFox?

Comment: I don't see you defining `.clear` styles in the CSS you provided, maybe that's why it didn't work. The `overflow` method is preferable since it means you aren't adding an element just to clear floats.

Comment: It's defined, I just didn't post it. The overflow method is not always ideal, though, because I may need to allow the content to overflow in some instances. I looked into the problem a little more and found some good answers on css-tricks.com. I just never knew that IE handled things in such a way.